# How to enable the Security tab in Explorer folder properties?

Tags: windows-xp, security

I am using Windows XP Professional SP2 and am logging on with an administrator account.

When I right click on any folder and choose Properties I am unable to see the "Security" and "Customize" tabs. How can I enable these tabs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you format your HDD in NTFS or FAT32?

FAT32 doesn't have that feature so NTFS does.

Also, you can enable the simple sharing:

http://www.petri.co.il/enable_simple_file_sharing_in_windows_xp.htm

Comment: oh! I have formatted it in FAT32

Comment: Ah! Read this ( http://www.aumha.org/win5/a/ntfscvt.php ) if you want it in NTFS. And upvote please :)

Comment: I do not have enough credits to give up vote .So i checked your answer as the desired answer.